# Linux - Windows 8 - Samba - Can see dir and contents but not create

Tags: linux

I have the following setup

Raspberry pi with samba installed and running

Windows 8 machine that can see the samba share, access the proper DIR, see all contents

In the smb.conf file, at the base of the file, I created the above dir with this

```
[AirLock]
comment = AirLock
path = /thepath/
writeable = Yes
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
browseable = Yes
public = Yes
read only = no
```

With these settings I can see the whole dir that I want but I cant create files, edit files, or create DIRs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being the `dir permissions`

They were restrictivly set

It had nothing to do with samba

```
sudo chmod -R 0777 "/theDirIwantToAccess/"
```

This will fix this problem

Comment: This may work but creates a large  security hole; in general world writable directories and files are a mistake. While it works it is not really the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the user password to the Samba password file?  You can do this with this command:

```
smbpasswd -a pi
```

If this command isn't found, run

```
sudo apt-get install samba-common-bin
```

and then try the previous command again.

Also, change public to 'no' and restart Samba.  When you connect from your Windows machine, you'll be prompted for pi's username and password.  Setting it up this way means Samba knows you're not an anonymous user, so it gives you the access rights of user pi.